# Steps to update Buffalo 300nh firmware to dd-wrt w/o connecting to internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I already have an existing wireless router that I rent from my ISP.

I want to setup my Buffalo 300nh router first, with new dd-wrt firmware and once I have that setup I will switch to using it.

What are the steps to do this?
Can I use my existing wireless, and then just connect using a cable to the 300nh router?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect the 300nh behind the existing router.  Just make sure that the local LAN settings on the 300nh are on a different subnet than the existing router.  For example if the existing router is serving up addresses in the 192.168.1.100 range make sure the 300nh is set to serve up addresses in the 192.168.2.100 range.  That should eliminate confusion between the routers.
However you don't really need to have them both connected.  Just download the latest dd-wrt firmware using the existing router to your computer. Then connect your computer via  a cable to the 300nh (which dosen't need to be connected to the internet yet) and upload the new firmware.  Once that is finished and all the settings are set, then swap the routers.

Comment: the 300nh distributes 192.168.11.0/24 by default, so shouldn't clash. DD-WRT will then change it to 192.168.1.0/24 iirc (I have one